# How do you filter table column names in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

The use case is, say you have a table with a lot of columns (100+) and you want to see if a certain column name exists in the table.  Another use case is, say there is a name scheme for the columns in the table that allows me to search for a term that will show all fields with that name - e.g. all fields related to a payment card are prefixed with "card_".

In MySQL I could handle both cases above by doing a `show fields in <table_name> like '%<search_term>%'`. I've googled for a solution but have only found results related to filtering actual table names and showing table schemas (e.g. \d+), which is not what I am looking for.  I've also tried variations of the MySQL command in the psql shell, but no luck.

I'm looking for a way to do this with SQL or with some other Postgres built-in way. Right now I'm resorting to copying the table schema to a text file and searching through it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query `information_schema.columns` using `table_name` and `column_name`. For example:

```
>= select table_name, column_name
   from information_schema.columns
   where table_name = 'users'
     and column_name like '%password%';

 table_name |      column_name
------------+------------------------
 users      | encrypted_password
 users      | reset_password_token
 users      | reset_password_sent_at
```